# Property file not available in bin folder while building in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a Project that I have built on Eclipse. I have a property file added in the src directory. The java class file is available in bin, but the property file is not available. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what kind of project is this?Example Java, Plugin. C/C++, Maven etc...

Comment: Upload the screen shot here http://postimage.org/ and share the link.

Comment: The package structure can be seen here http://postimg.org/image/m52ajo59z/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type of project is `Java Project`

Right click on the project and select properties option. Check in the Java build path all files under source folder are included or not and also check if some files are excluded.

In my case property file is being copied to **bin** folder. See the picture below.
Hierarchy of **source** folder and **bin** folder are same in my case.

[image]

If project is of type `plugin project`

Open the **Manifest.mf** file in **Plugin Manifest editor** and go to **Build** tab. Check the `property file is selected here` if NOT then select the file and check.

#### Edit:

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Simply Restart eclipse and completely clean and build the workspace and check.

Comment: Thanks Chandrayya. It is a Java project and a very simple one at that. :). I had already checked the build path and it is the same as you specified. But still I am not able to get the *.properties file

Comment: post your Java project folder structure, Is this project using `Java Builder` or any other builder like `Ant Builder`?Also verify that `Project > Build Automatically` option is selected or not. If not selected then select it or do manual build.

Comment: I am using the Java builder. This is a simple structure, with a package for Java files and a package for *.properties files. (Not able to add the image here)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.   It had been working and then stopped working for no apparent reason.  I fixed it by doing a clean build.   I don't know why the problem happened or why the clean build fixed it.